# Subsetting by rows to do a correlation

Tags: r, count, grouping, rows

I created a data frame from another dataset with 332 ID's. I split the data frame by IDs and would like to do a count rows of each ID and then do a correlation function. Can someone tell me how to do a count of the rows of each ID in order to do a correlation from these individual groups.

```
jlhoward your suggestion to add "table(dat1$ID)" command worked. My other problem is the function will not stop running                  
corr<-function(directory,threshold=)
#######  file location path#####                                   
for(i in 1:332){dat<-rbind(dat,read.csv(specdata1[i]))
  dat1<-dat[complete.cases(dat),]
  dat2<-(split(dat1,dat1$ID))
  list(dat2)            
  dat3<-table(dat1$ID)
  for (i in dat1>=threshold){
  x<-dat1$sulfate
  y<-dat1$nitrate
  correlations<-cor(x,y,use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")
corrs_output<-c(corrs_output,correlations) 

}
```

I'm trying to correlate the "sulfate" and "nitrate of each ID monitor that fits a threshold. I created a list that has all the complete cases per ID monitor. I need the function to do a correlation for "sulfate" and "nitrate of every set per ID that's => the threshold argument in the function. Below is the head and tail of the structure of the data.frame/list of each data set within the main data set "specdata1".

> head of entire data.frame/list of specdata1 complete cases for
>   correlation

```
head(str(dat2,1))
List of 323
 $ 1  :'data.frame':    117 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date   : Factor w/ 4018 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 279 285 291 297 303 315 321 327 333 339 ...
  ..$ sulfate: num [1:117] 7.21 5.99 4.68 3.47 2.42 1.43 2.76 3.41 1.3 3.15 ...
  ..$ nitrate: num [1:117] 0.651 0.428 1.04 0.363 0.507 0.474 0.425 0.964 0.491 0.669 ...
  ..$ ID     : int [1:117] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

> tail of entire data.frame/list for all complete cases of specdata1

```
tail(str(dat2,1))
$ 99 :'data.frame': 479 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date   : Factor w/ 4018 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1774 1780 1786 1804 1810 1816 1822 1840 1852 1858 ...
  ..$ sulfate: num [1:479] 1.51 8.2 1.48 4.75 3.47 1.19 1.77 2.27 2.06 2.11 ...
  ..$ nitrate: num [1:479] 0.725 1.64 1.01 6.81 0.751 1.69 2.08 0.996 0.817 0.488 ...
  ..$ ID     : int [1:479] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

Comment: `table(dat1$ID)` will give you a count of each `ID`. You need to explain what you want to correlate.

Comment: Thank you jlhoward. I added to correlation info. I'm running the code with the added line "table(dat1$ID)".

Comment: jlhoward your suggestion to add "table(dat1$ID)" command worked. My other problem is the function will not stop running